# Rails - prevent textarea from ignoring whitespace/special characters

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, actionview

I have the following string being output into a textarea as a variable in my view. It's an AJAX call and I can see via the response that the spaces are being passed through. However, all the whitespace is ignored in my textarea. How can I prevent this?

```
"status": "success",
"matches": "1",
"results":
    {
        "id": "56342", 
        "call_date": "2011-08-24 00:00:00",
        "tracking_number": "12223334444",
        "ringto_number": "12223334444",
        "direction": "inbound",
        "duration": "127",
        "file_url": "http://www.logmycalls.com/recordings/somesound.mp3",
        "reviewer": "admin@myaccount.com",
        "scorer": "user@myaccount.com",
        "score_grade": "87",
        "score_outcome": "pass",
        "status": "active"
    }
]
```

This is what it looks like in the textarea:

```
[
"status": "success",
"matches": "1",
"results":
{
"id": "56342", 
"call_date": "2011-08-24 00:00:00",
"tracking_number": "12223334444",
"ringto_number": "12223334444",
"direction": "inbound",
"duration": "127",
"file_url": "http://www.logmycalls.com/recordings/somesound.mp3",
"reviewer": "admin@myaccount.com",
"scorer": "user@myaccount.com",
"score_grade": "87",
"score_outcome": "pass",
"status": "active"
}
]
```

Comment: When you're looking at the response maybe the browser has done text formating for you.

Comment: I mean the response from the AJAX call in firebug... the spaces are there. I added the css property "white-space: pre" but it then showed as tabs.

Comment: Just kidding. The CSS property fixed it. Those tabs were actually a part of the string. :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Css property:

```
white-space: pre;
```